# Finite logarithm moment generating function

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm having troubles solving this problem:

Let $\mu$ a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\Lambda(t) \in [-\infty,\infty]$ $t \in \mathbb{R}$, be the logarithm moment generating function of $\mu$, i.e. $$\Lambda(t) = \log\int_\mathbb{R} e^{tx}d\mu(x)$$
Prove that if exists $r > 0$ such that $\Lambda(t) < \infty \forall |t| < r$ then $\mathbb{E}(\max_{i=1,\dots,N} X_i) < \infty$ when $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed from $\mu$.

I'm really stuck with this, any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: It's a standard Chernoff bounding technique. $e^{tE(M_n)}\le E(e^{tM_n})\le nE(e^{tX})$, Hence for $t>0$, $E(M_n)\le \frac{\log n+\Lambda(t)}t$, so pick any $t\in(0,r)$. You can minimize the RHS over all $t$ to get a possibly decent upper bound. In case of standard normal $X$ ($\Lambda(t)=t^2/2$), the optimized bound yields $E(M_n)\le\sqrt{2\log n}$ - very close to the real value of $E(M_n)$.

Comment: @A.S. Perhaps you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) along with fact that $$\mathbb{E}\left(e^{t\max\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)}\right)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(e^{tX_{i}}\right)=n\mathbb{E}\left(e^{tX}\right)=ne^{\Lambda(t)}.$$